# How to get original URL form 301 redirection

Tags: php, http-status-code-301

I want to get original URL (user entered URL) from 301 redirected URL.
Ex:

www.mydomain.com/about-1/

www.mydomain.com/about-2/

www.mydomain.com/about-3/

All above URLs want to redirect www.mydomain.com/about/. So I did it using simple `.htaccess` redirect. My problem is how to find from where user came (which original URL).
I've tried `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` but it didn't work.

Passing variable like `www.mydomain.com/about-1/?val=1` may a easy solution but it is not possible in this situation.

Comment: How did u do this using .htaccess? Can you show me the code?

Comment: @Ravinder Singh  `Redirect 301 /about-1/ http://www.mydomain.com/about/`

Comment: Do it using PHP to get referrer url....

Comment: Is it give original URL as referrer url in 301 redirection?

Comment: Yes it does give that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the HTTP_REFERER in _SERVER tells you where it is from. What I do sometimes is append a parameter to the url (either with a script.php?param=source or with a path script.php/path) to help me make the processing easier. These parameters can be added transparently to the script with an htaccess rule)

Comment: "These parameters can be added transparently to the script with an htaccess rule" seems good idea i will try

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to do this is to take the url of the referrer to www.mydomain.com/about/ URL as a variable.

```
<?php header("Location: http://www.mydomain.com/about?referrer=http://www.mydomain.com/about-1" ,TRUE,301); ?>
```

Then you always have the referrer with the $_GET variable.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it using `PHP`. Here is the link to get code to do it.

http://www.phpjunkyard.com/tutorials/php-redirect.php